# Mondrian Kylin Connection

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, kylin

does somebody has a valid and working example of a Mondrian to Kylin connection? 
I found that the unique version on Mondrian made to run standalone far away from other things from Pentaho / Saiku is available from [this report on github](https://github.com/rpbouman/xmondrian/tree/master/dist).

So I downloaded the war and moved it into the tomcat's web apps dir, then I upgraded some Jar as suggested [in this website](https://github.com/mustangore/kylin-mondrian-interaction).

The problem is that nothing seems to work.

I have defined a datasource as follow:

datasources\ -\ kylin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/installation.php#5_1_Describe_the_data_sources_in_datasources.xml
-->
<DataSources>
  <DataSource>
    <DataSourceName>test</DataSourceName>
    <DataSourceDescription>test from kylin</DataSourceDescription>
    <URL>http://localhost:8080/xmondrian/xmla</URL>
    <DataSourceInfo>Provider=mondrian; Jdbc=jdbc:kylin://192.168.127.100:7070/Luca_test; JdbcDrivers=org.apache.kylin.jdbc.Driver; JdbcUser=ADMIN; JdbcPassword=KYLIN</DataSourceInfo>
    <ProviderName>Mondrian</ProviderName>
    <ProviderType>MDP</ProviderType>
    <AuthenticationMode>Unauthenticated</AuthenticationMode>
    <Catalogs>
        <Catalog name="test">
            <Definition>/WEB-INF/schema/test.xml</Definition>
        </Catalog>
    </Catalogs>
  </DataSource>
</DataSources>
```

test.xml ( the schema )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Schema name="schema qualcosa" description="ancora di +" measuresCaption="bho" defaultRole="non lo so">
  <Cube name="il nome del cubo" caption="non ho idea di cosa possa essere" visible="true" description="come sopra + esteso" cache="false" enabled="true">
    <Table name="SAK_FACT_TRANSACTIONS" schema="UNIFIEDDATA_WORK" alias="transaction">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="PRICE" name="SAK_FACT_TRANSACTIONS_PRICE">
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="price" column="PRICE" datatype="Numeric" aggregator="sum" formatter="$#,##0.00" description="price come sopra" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

And tomcat logs show:

```
10:06:06,331 ERROR [XmlaServlet] Errors when handling XML/A message
mondrian.xmla.XmlaException: Mondrian Error:XMLA Discover unparse results error
        at mondrian.xmla.XmlaHandler.discover(XmlaHandler.java:2904)
        at mondrian.xmla.XmlaHandler.process(XmlaHandler.java:671)
        at mondrian.xmla.impl.DefaultXmlaServlet.handleSoapBody(DefaultXmlaServlet.java:507)
        at mondrian.xmla.XmlaServlet.doPost(XmlaServlet.java:318)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at mondrian.olap.Util.readURL(Util.java:3243)
        at mondrian.server.UrlRepositoryContentFinder.getContent(UrlRepositoryContentFinder.java:44)
        at mondrian.server.FileRepository.getServerInfo(FileRepository.java:236)
        at mondrian.server.FileRepository.getConnection(FileRepository.java:117)
        at mondrian.server.MondrianServerImpl.getConnection(MondrianServerImpl.java:262)
        at mondrian.xmla.XmlaHandler.getConnection(XmlaHandler.java:2976)
        at mondrian.xmla.XmlaHandler.getConnection(XmlaHandler.java:177)
        at mondrian.xmla.Rowset.populate(Rowset.java:219)
        at mondrian.xmla.Rowset.unparse(Rowset.java:194)
        at mondrian.xmla.XmlaHandler.discover(XmlaHandler.java:2898)
        ... 27 more
```

The schema has been validated into the [workbench-schema](https://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/workbench.php).
Any help is appreciated and welcomed.
Any help.

Comment: I feel that very less people are using Mondrian with Kylin. Apache Superset is an easier solution that you can try.

Comment: Any other solution which can help to use Excel with Kylin's cube is welcomed, I need  a way to allow excel to execute MDX query over Kylin which allows the pivot tables to work correctly.